# Excel SUMIFS equivalent code in Power BI (note, SUMIFS not SUMIF please!)

Tags: excel, powerbi, left-join, sumifs

I am looking for a way to replicate what **SUMIFS** can do in Excel in Power BI.

I have 2 tables:

Table A

```
Year    Region   Value A     
2010    North     100          
2010    East      200         
2010    West      500        
2010    South     300         
2011    North     150          
2011    East      250         
2011    West      550          
2011    South     350
```

Table B

```
 Year    Region   Value B
 2011    North        0
 2011    East         0
 2011    West         0
 2011    South        0
 2011    North     1000
 2011    East      2000
 2011    West      3000
 2011    South     4000
```

I would like to have Table A amended to look like this, so populated by looking up BOTH Year and Region variables in Table A and pulling the data from B:

```
Year    Region   Value A   Value B
 -------------------------------
2010    North     100        1000
2010    East      200        2000
2010    West      500        3000
2010    South     300        4000
2011    North     150           0
2011    East      250           0
2011    West      550           0
2011    South     350           0
2011    North     450           0
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the logic for 2011 entries in Table B showing up on the 2011 lines from Table A?  What does SUMIFS have to do with this result?  In Excel, it would be INDEX?MATCH

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks.  SUMIFS would be the simplest (and in my opinion, most efficient way to return the result in Excel (maybe FILTER as you suggest is as good or better but I am new to 365 and POWER BI!)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a typo in your Table B and the last four rows should really be from 2010, based on your posted desired output. I am also assuming that the last row in your desired results is a typo, as there is no `2011 North 450` in Table A

Also, I have no idea what SUMIFS has to do with this.  In Excel, I would be using `INDEX/MATCH` (perhaps `FILTER` in Office 365).

That being the case, you simply need to `Join` the two tables using, as keys, the `Year` and `Region`.

Please read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm.

```
let

//Read in both tables and set data types
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],

    //add Index column for sorting at the end
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Region", type text}, {"Value A", Int64.Type}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableB"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Region", type text}, {"Value B", Int64.Type}}),

//join tables based on Region and Year
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Year","Region"},#"Changed Type2",{"Year","Region"},"joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//add column with the "Value B"
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(joined, "Custom", each [joined][Value B]{0}),

//remove joined table column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"joined"}),

//sort back to original order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

//remove the Index column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks.  I am new to Power BI so this is quite complex, was hoping for a simpler solution using DAX rather than M?

Comment: @4agreements Then I suggest you develop some DAX formulas and edit your question to show your research and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Hi Ron, I used a left outer join merge queries in POWER BI using Year and Region.  The problem I have is I want to have only one year column (sync'd with Table A Year) but I had two Year columns and the data was not aligned correctly?  Hope that makes sense, bit difficult to explain?

Comment: @4agreements Not really given the sample data you posted.   As you can see from the screenshots, with the assumptions I made about your typos,  there is only one year column in the results.

Comment: @4agreements And why did you choose to change the jointype from what I recommended?

Comment: Hi Ron, I am working in Power BI Desktop Power Query, there is no option for a Nested / Custom join in the Merge Queries selection..... please remember I am new to Power BI also.  Thanks

Comment: @4agreements but you **can** define the join type. Also. Also, consider familiarizing yourself with how to use the advanced editor.

Comment: Thanks anyway Ron, I found another solution!